# Values in 2 dimensional array

Tags: c

myArray and q print 0 and I can't figure out why.

```
printf("Diameter: %f Flow rate: %f\n",myArray[rows][columns],q);
```

The program calculates flow rate and I'm trying to print a table with the diameter and flow rate values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printArray(float myArray[5][3], float v);

int main()
{
    float q, a, d, v, array[5][3];
    int rows, columns;

    printf("Enter: ");
    scanf("%f",&v);

    for (rows = 0; rows < 5; rows++ )
    {
        for ( columns = 0; columns < 3; columns++)
        {
            printf("Enter value for %d, %d",rows,columns);
            scanf("%d",&array[rows][columns]);
        }
    }
    printArray(array, v);

}

void printArray(float myArray[5][3], float v)
{
    int i, rows, columns;
    float q, a;

    for (rows = 0; rows < 5; rows++ )
    {
        for ( columns = 0; columns < 3; columns++)
        {
            a=(3.14*(myArray[rows][columns]*myArray[rows][columns]))/4;
            q=a*v;
            printf("Diameter: %f Flow rate: %f\n",myArray[rows][columns],q);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: One issue is that you reading an int into a float. You have the wrong format specifier for the scanf that reads into the array.

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%d",&array[rows][columns]);
```

You are using `%d` to scan into `float`, which is undefined behaviour. You need to use `%f` instead. Also, you should check the return value of `scanf` to ensure it has successfully scanned something. `scanf` returns the number of items successfully scanned, so in your case it should return 1. If there was no suitable input, it will return 0, or if there was an error reading the input, it will return `EOF`.

For example, you could have:

```
if (scanf("%f", &array[rows][columns]) != 1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read input\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, really helped out.